# created Public key and private key but unable to login VM by using Putty, how to overcome this issue? and I'm copy those keys and saved as .ppk file?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm-template, terraform-template-file

created Public key and private key but unable to  login VM by using Putty, how to overcome this issue?
and I'm copy those keys and saved as .ppk but those keys not working login by using putty??

```
# Create (and display) an SSH key

resource "tls_private_key" "example_ssh" {
  algorithm = "RSA"`
  rsa_bits = 4096
}
output "tls_private_key" { 
    value = tls_private_key.example_ssh.private_key_pem 
    sensitive = true
}
 admin_ssh_key {
        username       = "azureuser"
        public_key     = tls_private_key.example_ssh.public_key_openssh
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the definition of your vm?

Comment: source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "18.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked for me like this:

```
resource "tls_private_key" "example_ssh" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "local_file" "private_key" {
  content         = tls_private_key.example_ssh.private_key_pem
  filename        = "example.pem"
  file_permission = "0600"
}

admin_ssh_key {
  username   = "azureuser"
  public_key = tls_private_key.example_ssh.public_key_openssh
}
```

And then `ssh -i example.pem azureuser@PUBLIC_IP`.

NOTE: Please do not forget to allow SSH Port 22 via Inbound Rule (NSG) on the NIC or the Subnet.

Comment: How to download "example.pem" file ?
I run this command in windows power shell ssh -i example.pem azureuser@PUBLIC_IP with my public_IP. I got this error
Warning: Permanently added 'mypublic_ip' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
azureuser@Mypublic_ip: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: with the local_file resource from the terraform [local provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file) the file gets created.

Comment: Nice !! Could you please mark my answer as the correct solution?

Comment: Kinda rough if using as a part of a DevOps pipeline, as the key gets stored on the ephemeral runner and then...lost?